# Прописать код проще

Tags: javascript

```
(dt = new FormData()).append('md', 'v');
dt.append('po', 'stats');
dt.append('wi', sessionStorage.getItem('wi'));
dt.append('rf', sessionStorage.getItem('rf'));
dt.append('id', sessionStorage.getItem('id'));
navigator.sendBeacon("/ajax/", dt);
```

Каким образом, возможно прописать проще. Напрягает, когда необходимо добавлять каждый параметр по отдельности. Нет бы сразу массивом...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подготовьте набор вспомогательных функций:

```
function storage_get(key) {
  return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
}

if (FormData.prototype.appendAll) {
  throw new Error("Метод с названием appendAll уже встроен в FormData.\n" + 
                  "Измените название");
}

FormData.prototype.appendAll = function(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    this.append(key, obj[key]);
  }

  return this;
};

/***/
let dt = new FormData().appendAll({
  'md': 'v',
  'po': 'stats',
  'wi': storage_get('wi'),
  'rf': storage_get('rf'),
  'id': storage_get('id'),
});

navigator.sendBeacon("/ajax/", dt);
```

`FormData.prototype.appendAll`... У каждой функции есть свойство `prototype`. Оно хранит объект, свойства которых будут доступны всем объектам-экземплярам, созданным через вызов функции с оператором `new` → `new FormData()`

`this` внутри метода: «объект перед точкой» при вызове метода `new FormData().appendAll()`, т.е. созданный (new FormData())

---

Конечно, можно и не лезть в прототип, а записать обычную функцию:

```
function storage_get(key) {
  return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
}

function appendAll(instance, obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    instance.append(key, obj[key]);
  }

  return instance;
};

/***/
let dt = appendAll(new FormData(), {
  'md': 'v',
  'po': 'stats',
  'wi': storage_get('wi'),
  'rf': storage_get('rf'),
  'id': storage_get('id'),
});

navigator.sendBeacon("/ajax/", dt);
```

Comment: Возможно прописать как нибудь так `FormData.prototype.appendAll = obj => {` ?? Привычка писать именно так... Не выходит

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов Нельзя) У стрелочных функций нет своего `this`.

Answer (score 5):

Не проверял, но думаю должно работать

```js
class CustomFormData extends FormData {
  append(name, value) {
    super.append(name, value)
    return this
  }
  appendAsSpread(...args) {
    for (let arg of args) {
      super.append(...arg)
    }
    return this
  }
  appendAsMap(map) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(map)) {
      super.append(key, value)
    }
    return this
  }
}

const fd = new CustomFormData()
fd.append('name', 'Vasy')
  .append('surname', 'Lihachev')
  .appendAsSpread(['file', new Blob([1, 2, 3]), 'filename'], ['file2', new Blob([1, 2, 3]), 'filename'])
  .appendAsMap({
    key1: 'data1',
    key2: 'data2'
  })

console.log(
  [...fd.entries()]
)
```

Comment: `appendAsMap`: `appendAsSpread(...Object.entries(map))`

Comment: @Grundy да, можно перекинуть

Comment: Наталкивает на идею сделать один append, который будет проверять тип и количество прилетевших аргументов = работать со всем подряд)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Вот я не смог додуматься как использовать с объектом appendAsMap три аргумента, а так бы да было здорово